# How to suppress # being a mark-up character in doxygen

Tags: c++, c, doxygen

I'm using `///` comments to generate doxygen doc from my C++ code. In those comments, I want to use the character '#' as an ordinary text character -- I often use it to mean "number of" as in "returns the number of cells". However,

```
/// # elements in full blocks, given # elements
```

in my C++ source code generates the following in the doxygen html output

**elements in full blocks, given # elements**

in bold and very large font. Thus, the first # is interpreted as some mark-up character. How can I suppress this? Is there a setting for the .dox file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just escape it using `\#`.

See the documentation here: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdhash